# Change or convert only text of radio buttons but not the values in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

This is my code below:

```
<form name="mainform" id="mainform" class="form_step" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<ol>
<li id="list_cp_ad_type">
  <div class="labelwrapper">
     <label>
           <a href="#" tip="Choose your ad type" tabindex="999" title="Choose your ad type">
              <div class="helpico"></div>
                </a>Ad Type: <span class="colour">*</span>
     </label>
  </div>
        <ol class="radios">
        <li><input value="Offer Ads" type="radio" class="radiolist required" name="cp_ad_type" id="cp_ad_type">&nbsp;&nbsp;Offer Ads</li>
        <li><input value="Wanted Ads" type="radio" class="radiolist required" name="cp_ad_type" id="cp_ad_type">&nbsp;&nbsp;Wanted Ads</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="clr"></div>
</li>
```

Expected code:

```
<form name="mainform" id="mainform" class="form_step" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<ol>    
    <li id="list_cp_ad_type">
                <div class="labelwrapper">
                        <label>
                            <a href="#" tip="Choose your ad type" tabindex="999" title="Choose your ad type">
                            <div class="helpico"></div>
                             </a>Ad Type: <span class="colour">*</span>
                       </label>
                </div>
               <ol class="radios">
               <li><input value="Offer Ads" type="radio" class="radiolist required" name="cp_ad_type" id="cp_ad_type">I Offer this</li>
               <li><input value="Wanted Ads" type="radio" class="radiolist required" name="cp_ad_type" id="cp_ad_type">I Want this</li>
               </ol>
               <div class="clr"></div>
    </li>
```

I just want to convert or change only "  Offer Ads" text to "I Offer this" text and "  Wanted Ads" text to "I Want this" text but not the input values of both id="cp_ad_type" that too with immediate effect on page loading.

Anyone plz helpme..

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is not very clear. HOW do you want to change the text - via jQuery? And what do you mean: "*that too with immediate effect on page loading*"?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('.radios input:radio[value="Offer Ads"]').get(0).nextSibling.data  = 'I offer this'
    $('.radios input:radio[value="Wanted Ads"]').get(0).nextSibling.data = 'I Want this'
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GhpZb/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as you tagged it. This may work for you,

```
$('input:radio[value="Offer Ads"]').parent().text('I Offer this');
$('input:radio[value="Wanted Ads"]').parent().text('I Want this');
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/GbmTJ/)

I suggest, though, using a different [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) for each element, otherwise it won't be valid HTML. Quoting the W3C docs:

> There must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same
>   id value.

Answer (score 0):

IDs are meant to be unique, assign unique ids to each radio button, or use classes instead

try this

```
function change()
{
document.getElementById('cp_ad_type').setAttribute('value',"your value");

}
```